# How can I run an embedded .exe file in C# Windows Forms applications?

Tags: c#, file, process, exe

How can I run an embedded .exe file (installer) in C# Windows Forms applications the easiest way?

I just want to click a button and an installer should open. My .exe file's name is `setup`.

If I try `Process.Start(setup.exe);` I get an error:

> The name 'setup' does not exist in the current context

And if I try

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("setup");
```

it will open folder `C:\Windows\System32\setup`.

Comment: have you tried giving full path of exe incluing the folder its contained in ?

Comment: That's all you gotta do.

Comment: the exe file is embedded to the program, it hasn't got any external path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you expect is the easiest way, then don't embed `setup.exe` as a **resource**, but as **Content**.

(Add `setup.exe` to your project, and right click on setup.exe in Solution Explorer to edit properties, set as content, and select *Copy* if newer.)

**Another option** if `setup.exe` is a project of your Visual Studio solution, is to **automatically copy** `setup.exe` in the output directory of the launcher project: Add a reference to `setup.exe` if it belongs to the solution, so it is automatically copied every time you compile and there was a change.

Last is the code that is pretty easy - you already have it, actually:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("HelloWorld.exe");
```

If needed, you can change the current directory:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"c:\someSetupExeDir";
```

But better, you can use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8):

```
String fullPath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :D                                                                     Regards